# Substracting two's complement

Tags: math, binary, twos-complement

B=01010101
A=10101010

**They are already in two's complement and I have to do B - A.**

I don't know what to do, because if A has a 1 it means that it's a negative number. Then the operation is  B - (-A) or B + A.

But B+A=11111111 (000000001 in binary) and that doesn't seem correct.

Maybe I'm not "getting it", but I really don't know what I should be doing.

Comment: B=85, A=-86. A + B = -1. A - B = A + ~B + 1 = ?

Comment: start with some smaller examples (eg. 3 bits long) and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Your task is to find B-A. If A is a negative number then A = -C where C = 86 in this case.
So in other words B-A = B+C (NOT B+A).
You should simply calculate C from A (reverse all the single bits and then add one: 01010101+1 = 01010110) and then you sum B to the calculated number:

Considering A and B both in two's complement:
I think the answer is 10101011 or -85!!
Here is why:

```
      01010101 (-171)
  +   01010110 (86)
**=   10101011 (-85)**
```

Comment: Or in terms of an 8-bit signed value, -256+171 = -85

Comment: I have just got to that point. Nice to see I finally was thinking correctly. The problem is that the exercise asks for a 8-bit number, so I'm not sure which one is the answer. -85 is 8-bit but wrong, 171 is 9-bit but correct... @ChronoKitsune